# Canned unopened and unrefrigerated juice lasts longer in the pantry than the freezer?

Tags: storage-lifetime, juice

Apple juice unrefrigerated, canned, and unopened [lasts](http://stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/16373) 1-1.5 years in the pantry but only .75-1 year in the freezer according to stilltasty.com.

Blackberry juice lasts as long as apple juice does in pantry and freezer if it is unrefrigerated, canned, and unopened. So does cranberry juice, grape juice, grapefruit juice, lemon juice that is not from concentrate, lime juice not from concentrate, orange juice, pineapple juice, pomegranate juice, prune juice, tangerine juice, and carrot juice doesn't even last in the freezer according to stilltasty.com

Why would canned, unrefrigerated, unopened juice last longer in the pantry than the freezer? That seems counterintuitive because most things last the longest in the freezer.

Comment: stilltasty.com is the site I am getting it from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Still Tasty is making the assumption that you are freezing the juice AFTER opening it, not freezing the unopened cans. The heading of the info says "*Sold* in Unopened Cans", as it goes on in the text about freezing, it says, "Freeze in airtight glass or plastic container and leave at least 1/2 inch of headspace at the top, as juice will expand when frozen."

It makes no sense to freeze the unopened cans.

Note it also says that the limit on how long it will last in the freezer refers to quality only, if kept frozen, it will remain safe indefinitely.

Comment: yes it does but they are lying there about the limit. In the freezer if left there for months and months it can develop freezerburn which as you know is almost like cooking food in the freezer. Thus if kept frozen than there is no infinite shelf life. All shelf life has a limit, even aged cheddar has its limits.

Comment: But what they're saying is that it won't make you sick. They're not suggesting that it will be good forever. As a matter of fact, eventually it won't even be liquid any more once defrosted. But it will still be safe. Freezer burn isn't toxic, it just doesn't look or taste good.

Comment: when I see "This will last indefinitely" it makes me think that they are really saying that it will last for infinite time and thus lying about how long something lasts.

Comment: No @caters, they're not lying. They're saying that as long as the product stays frozen, it won't hurt you. They include the caveat concerning quality and recommend that you use use frozen juice within a year.

Comment: but nothing lasts for ∞ time. Especially when it is a finite amount of time before we get engulfed by the sun.

Comment: and if indefinitely is a synonym of infinite because of how both mean forever when talking about time than when they say "this will last indefinitely" it is the same as if they said "This will last infinitely long"

Comment: @caters, the line says that it will be safe *as long is it stays frozen*. Obviously, if the juice is being engulfed by the sun, it's no longer frozen.